# Google Calendar notifications not displaying

Tags: google-calendar

How do you get events on the Google Calendar app to display notifications on the phone?

### Steps I have tried:

1. Google Calendar app > Swiping left > Settings > (Calendar label) > Default Notifications: Set this to 1 minute before
2. Tapping on Google Calendar app > calendar item > edit > Notification: Set this to 1 minute before
3. Going to Phone OS system settings > Sound & Notification > App notifications > Calendar > Setting: Block all to 'off'; Treat as priority: on; Allow peeking: on;

Notes:

- My calendar events are created via the web at
  https://calendar.google.com
- Phone os: 6.0
- Phone: Moto E (2nd Gen)
- All events are NOT all day. Instead they last for 1 minute.

Comment: Try clearing the cache of calendar app on device. If that doesn't help remove and add the Google account to force a fresh sync